# In a MediaWiki, where can I find the list of all uploaded images?

Tags: mediawiki

In a MediaWiki, where can I find the list of all uploaded images ?

*(I had it a few weeks ago, now that I'm back on the project, can't find it in the interface.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching with different keyword, I finaly found the answer

```
http://[your wiki]/Special:ListFiles
```